# COUNTIFS & SUMIFS Functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I can't figure out why I get a zero "0" value when I set both criterias to "All" (from the drop down list I created), in cell "I50" and in cell "J50". I used "All" instead of a wildcard ("?*") because I wanted the cell to show the word All instead of displaying the wildcard. So I wrote a string to calculate when I select "All" in the cell.

I'm trying to show the number of items sold within a specified date range using criterias for Purchase Date (start/end), Region, & Sales Rep.

This is the formula I'm using;

```
  =IF(I50="All",COUNTIFS(Purchase_Date,">="&G50,Purchase_Date,"<="&H50,Sales_Reps,J50),IF(J50="All",COUNTIFS(Purchase_Date,">="&G50,Purchase_Date,"<="&H50,Region,I50),COUNTIFS(Region,I50,Sales_Reps,J50,Purchase_Date,">="&G50,Purchase_Date,"<="&H50)))
```

Comment: Just to note, the formula works when I select a different criteria in one or both of the cells (Region= Northeast and Sales_Rep= All). But it doesn't work when I select "All" in both cells.

Comment: A screen shot would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already tested it, and worked :)

```
=COUNTIFS(Purchase_Date,">="&G50,Purchase_Date,"<="&H50,Sales_Reps,IF(J50="All","*",J50),Region,IF(I50="All","*",I50))
```

Hopefully I reverted all changes coming from GER-version to US/GB-version

Comment: Can you explain where was the error

Comment: Your formula said: If i50="All" (or j50="All") add x1,x2,x3 and j50 (or i50) but if both is "All" you are trying to add a string to the numbers. I think...but I just went the other way and put in two IFs instead of one so I don't need such a large one that increases the complexity by a lot ;)

Comment: So, did it work for you? I would really appreciate some feedback ;)

Comment: Thanks @Hello Fishy, the formula works like a charm. It's so simple compared to what I was trying. I didn't know I could nest "IF" functions inside a criteria like that. I just learn something. Thank You.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad :) Appreciate the feedback and you are very welcome :)

Comment: There seems to have been some mix up with my comment, where I said "Did not work". I was replying to the formula @Selkie suggested trying, which did not work. However, the formula you provided is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your countif is using an AND if both are true, so it's only returning values where both are true, instead of trying to sum both. I'd modify it to be one countif + the other countif

```
=if(AND(I50="All",J50="All"),Countif(the count if for 150 being all)+Countif(*The countif for J50 being all),if(J50="All",Countif((The countif for J50 being all),if(I50="All",Countif(the count if for 150 being all),*What you want if neither one is all)))
```

Comment: Can you give an example. Because I've tried everything I can think of (including "&" and "+") but nothing seems to work. Thanks

Comment: =if(AND(I50="All",J50="All"),Countif(*the count if for 150 being all)+Countif(*The countif for J50 being all*),if(J50="All",Countif((*The countif for J50 being all*),if(I50="All",Countif(*the count if for 150 being all),*What you want if neither one is all*)))

Comment: Thanks @Selkie, However, the first part of that formula adds up or combines the two criterias, thus doubling the result. It returned a value of 6 whereas it should be 3.

This is the formula I typed;
=IF(AND(I50="All",J50="All"),COUNTIFS(Purchase_Date,">="&G50,Purchase_Date,"<="&H50)+COUNTIFS(Purchase_Date,">="&G50,Purchase_Date,"<="&H50),"")

Comment: An ugly work-around - if it always returns double, could you divide the result by 2?